# Custom token for Events in scheduled reminder s

Tags: civievent, tokens, scheduled-reminders

We tried to follow https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/10907/7846 from Noah Miller
to use a custom event token in a scheduled reminder without success.
We dumped all the variables used by the  hook civicrm_tokenValues ($values, $cids, $job, $tokens and $context) but we could not get the event_id even if Noah says it is available.

```
$event_id = CRM_Utils_Array::value('event.event_id', $values)
```

stays null.

So is it possible to use a custom event token in a scheduled reminder and if yes, how do we get the $event_id ?

Comment: What entity are you using for the scheduled reminder?

Comment: For my test, I tried "Event Name" but in production, it will be event type...

Comment: Event type is not working either...